# How to save an Excel Workbook in Excel Online as a PDF file?

Tags: excel, pdf, office-scripts

My goal is to save an Excel workbook (living in Excel online) as PDF, preferably to MS OneDrive or Sharepoint, but if need be to my local PC.

My question is if this is even possible at the moment?

This is what I've done so far:

- Look for a save-as (PDF) possibility in Excel online: does not seem to be available.
- Look for an export possibility in Excel line: does not seem to be available.
- With Office script: recorded the following string of actions: Print -> Download: opens up a new tab, when going back to the original Excel Online tab in the browser nothing seems to be recorded.
- Btw: when I do Print -> Download without recording, ofcourse the Excel is downloaded to my local PC, but with name "Document". Outside a rename on my local PC, there does not seem to be a way to rename the document just before/while downloading. Or is there?

Why do I need this functionality (meaning: to be able to save an Excel online Excel Workbook as .PDF)? This is because I create from one Excel Workbook a lot of other Excel Workbooks which I then need to save as Excel as well as as PDF. This in order to generate multiple pricelists for multiple languages from one "mother" Excel Workbook. Currently I do this with "local" Excel / VBA, but I want to migrate this to the cloud. This currently does not seem to be possible without making it much more complex or does not seem to be possible at all.

Many thanks in advance for any tips or directions about a suitable approach.

Comment: You can do this with PowerAutomate. So Office Scripts is not necessary to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the OneDrive for Business connector in Power Automate to convert a file. Here are a few resources

- [OneDrive for Business connector documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedriveforbusiness/)
- [Power Automate's OneDrive for Business overview page](https://preview.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_onedriveforbusiness/onedrive-for-business/)
- [Copy as pdf template on Power Automate](https://preview.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/913e5a8780784787b21ed28f0283913a/copy-as-a-pdf/)